# Multhreading Java double for loop with boolean inside

Tags: java, multithreading, for-loop

I would like to know if I can multithread my double for loop in this case.
in the second for loop I send a boolean to true if some condition is done and I
use the result of this boolean in the first loop. Does multithreading corrupt the result in this case? If not does it increase speed of calculation event with that?

here is my code:

```
ArrayList<Appartement> sorted = new ArrayList<>();
boolean ispresent = false;
for (Appartement p1: res2) {
     ispresent = false;
     for (Appartement p2: res2) {
         if (p1.equals(p2))
             continue;
             if (!p1.ContainNull() && !p2.ContainNull()){
             if (p1.getRoomCount().equals(p2.getRoomCount()) && p1.getPrice().equals(p2.getPrice()) && p1.getSurface().equals(p2.getSurface())
                            && p1.getZipCode().equals(p2.getZipCode()) && p1.getNewBuild().equals(p2.getNewBuild())
                            && p1.getPropertyType().equals(p2.getPropertyType()) && p1.getFurnished().equals(p2.getFurnished())
                            && p1.getMarketingType().equals(p2.getMarketingType())) {
                        ispresent = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
          if (!ispresent)
              sorted.add(p1);
     }
```

I would appreciate some help here.

Comment: why don't you try it and see?

Comment: It looks like you only want to build a list with all unique items without duplicates. You can actually do that in a single pass with O(n) complexity using a HashSet, so you certainly don't need multiple threads.

Comment: I am parsing a json file and when i try to use HashSet it puts all my appartment with duplicate in there so i tried this way. My class appartment got few string value and int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to create a new thread to run the code inside of each for loop? If you were to do that in your current implementation it would likely break, since the `ispresent` variable would be in scope for both threads which could definitely cause issues.

If you were to put the internal  for loop in a separate class entirely that ran the internal loop as a thread and took care of adding to the arraylist inside of that method like this psuedo code:

```
class threadedLoop{
 public void run() {
        //Do your loopy stuff
        //if ispresent then add to arraylist you passed as parameter
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        (new threadedLoop()).start();
    }
}
```

Then you would eliminate the risk of any possible conflicts and should see an improvement in the speed of your program! Take a look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html) to see how to implement the threads.

Comment: Thanks, yeah i gained some time and it didn't screw my result.

Comment: Glad it helped! If it was what you were looking for could you accept my answer? Much appreciated